# Check client connections on server architecture design?

Tags: java, client, rmi

I have a server and about 150 client machines.
All clients register to the server and server make method calls(callbacks) on registered clients.

At this  system Server pings all connected clients(ping is a callback method) periodically(connection liveness check). But if I do all clients ping operation in a thread. It is working too slow because of waiting times of method call at unavailable clients. And if a connection is broken it waits for timeout occur. So the waiting time is too long.
I have a new idea for connection liveness check.
That I will create a thread for each connected client. And each thread will just control own client. So All system connection check will be done by these threads.

Is it useful ?

Is there any other professional offer for this project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When checking your clients, server is acting as client to them, so it is actually two-way fair-right architecture. If you want a central node to be aware of client state, make clients 'say hello' to server by polling it with heartbeat message on certain interval. Once server does not receive next expected heartbeat, the client is considered dead. Starting more threads will not bring an advantage, but can rather result in poorer performance. Consider using worker thread or some kind of actor pattern to handle heartbeats.

Comment: Think that, client connected to the server object and called sayHello method. On the other hand server called a client method ... but this client does not response. (client can call server method but server can not call client method is it possible ? )
what you think ?

Comment: Server cannot call client by definition. It serves client's requests by sending responses. That's all.

Comment: server can do callbacks to the clients. This is mostly used mechanism. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/rmi/callbak.htm

Comment: You are not specific with what you are using and why. If you want to go with  RMI and Callbacks, then you have to base your question on that. Your question is about architecture.

Comment: I told my implementation on question. My server is pinging clients it means that my server object calls ping method on client callback.

Comment: No, you have nothing about callbacks in your question, it is rather blurry and high-level. Callback you are talking about is pure RMI. If you want an advice on how to implement your architecture with RMI, you should form your question correspondingly.

Comment: @ahanin This is a distinction without a difference. Callback *is* an architectural feature, and it certainly isn't just a feature of RMI.

Comment: @EJP, Callback is a pattern. RMI provides it as a feature. Is it possible with HTTP, for example? Well, no, unless you open another feedback channel for  receiving  callbacks only. I wanted to point that context is important if topic-starter wanted to receive an answer related to his specifics, rather than an advice on how to build architecture.

Comment: @ahanin No, RMI *doesn't* 'provide it as a feature'. It is just available as a consequence of the client-server *architecture* of RMI. It is possible with HTTP provided you have an HTTP server at both ends. In either case you need a separate connection for the callback.

Comment: @EJP, well, it is a feature, since it is possible :) Even if there is no separate interface for callback object and you have to implement your client as a server to be able to receive callbacks. Regarding HTTP, however, it is possible with message polling without using an HTTP server on client side. The concrete implementation may vary and can be inverted as with HTTP feedback-channel, but on a high-level, it is callbacks, servers and clients. Not mixing concepts helps a lot. Whatever, we are already far away from topic.

Comment: @ahanin (1) It is a feature of the underlying architecture, that's what makes it possible. You cannot point me to the 'RMI callback feature' because it doesn't exist. Contrary to your assertion above. (2) It is also possible with HTTP the way I described. Contrary to your assertion above that it isn't.

Comment: "It is not possible because it is not possible" is not a good way to describe 'why'. Think opening two separate HTTP connections to server's resources, e.g. /request, /callback. Server holds connection to the latter alive and uses it to push back callback messages as portions of the response body. Client would read those portions and treat them as callbacks. That's it. No matter what technology you use, RMI, the one I described, or anything else. Logically it's still client, server and a callback pattern. Even if the implementation assumes invertion of concepts.

Comment: @ahanin You aren't making any sense to me whatsoever. What is it that isn't possible? Surely you realize that an RMI callback is implemented by opening a 2nd connection in the reverse direction? and that the same technique will work for HTTP under the conditions I described?

Comment: @EJP, my efforts are gone in vain. This question has nothing to do with RMI, despite of rmi tag is present. Think broader than technology you use.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].